# Short URI to long URI by database query

Tags: php, mysql

In earlier attempts my code was prone to MySQL injections. So I went and studied prepared statements. My question is: although it works as needed, did I miss anything here? Security wise or otherwise.

The script translates a URI www.domain-a.com/123/ to www.domain-b.com/something/123/somethingelse/

```
<?php
    include_once 'includes/connect_db.php';

    // Fetch URI
    $shortUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // Remove slash 
    $shortUri = substr($shortUri, 1);
    // Define database query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'yadayada' AND post_name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%');";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "SQL statement failed";
    } else {
        // Bind params to placeholder
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $shortUri);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            mysqli_close($conn);
            // Merge TLD with URI from query
            $longUri = 'https://www.domain-b.nl/something/' . $row['post_name'];
            // Redirect to destination
            header('Location: '.$longUri);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is in WordPress you really should be using [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb) for all database access, not bypassing that with `mysqli`.

Comment: @tadman It is WordPress. What are risks here?

Comment: Not using WPDB is asking for trouble. WordPress has its own internals that should be respected when working with it. It's the *When in Rome* principle. If you're using WordPress you can probably get constants like the site base URL and such programmatically instead of having to hard-code them in like you've done here.

Comment: In other situations and you're using `mysqli`, use the object-oriented model, it's a lot less coding and way less error-prone. You'll also want to enable exceptions to avoid missing errors. That being said, you should be using PDO at the absolute minimum as it's a database-agnostic driver that has applications beyond just MySQL and offers features `mysqli` can't match, like named placeholders and easier binding.

Comment: @tadman As a beginner programmer I was happy I got it up and running, but I appreciate the input :-) I'll investigate WPDB. Thanks!